# Deactivating Events - Registration Cancellation Notice

Tags: civievent

every time i delete a participant in an event, a registration cancellation notice is sent to them. I would like to deactivate that function - I system workflow messages I can only change the content, but not deactivate this. I may have to change civievent code. Any hints where and how?
Best wishes, Michael

Answer (score 2):

This could either already solve your question and if not give a very good idea of where to look: https://civicrm.org/extensions/prevent-sending-event-registration-confirmation-back-office